# Copying from xlsx to an specific sheet in another xlsx

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, copying

I need some help with python. Basically I have 2 files(for this example will be file1 and file2). File1 have several sheets inside, file2 is just one sheet. So after some work in file2 now i have the DataFrame that i need. And I need to paste this DataFrame in one specific sheet in file1.

```
File1

  A       B       C       D         E          F         G
<data>  <data>  <data>  <data>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<data>  <data>  <data>  <data>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<data>  <data>  <data>  <data>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<data>  <data>  <data>  <data>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<data>  <data>  <data>  <data>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<data>  <data>  <data>  <data>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>

File2

    A          B          C         D         
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>

So now i need to update the file one with the new Data.

File1

    A          B          C         D           E          F         G         
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
<Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <Newdata>  <formula>  <formula>  <formula>
```

So the columns E,F and G have some formulas that are updated by the data in the columns A, B, C, D.

I try different options to do this. Concatenate both files and show the columns i try, load both files and create a new file with the new information... The main issue is that in the file1 i have several sheets, that i need to keep, because the columns E,F and G(The one with the formulas), will update other sheets.

So if someone give me a hand with this please. Thanks i will appreciate the help

Comment: Use `openpyxl`. It will be able to handle everything needed in the `.xlsx` file. If using `xlsx` for both files let me know and I will try to help the best I can.
Just noticed its an `xlsb` file. No idea on those :(

Comment: @Sid .xlsb is a big xlsx, i can use xlsx in both files, can you help me please

Comment: Hmmm..I can't seem to keep the data in rows E, F and G. Trying to figure out why. If you want I can post up the code till now.

Answer (score 0):

There is without a doubt a better way to do this but this is how I can do it:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

os.chdir("Directory Path here")
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
#or use the below to pick sheet as by name
# ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name
inde = []
val = []
for col in ws.iter_cols():
    for cell in col:
        h = cell.coordinate
        inde.append(h)
        v = cell.value
        val.append(v)
diction = dict(zip(inde,val))

wb1=load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

for i in diction.keys():
    ws1[i] = diction[i]
    wb1.save('file1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks Sid, let me try this solution.

Comment: Hi morning. Sorry for the long time to answer. No, did not  work. I´m receiving this error. 
       `for col in ws.iter_cols():
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'iter_cols'`

Comment: Strange, I just tried it out again and it works perfectly. Double check the code at your end?

Comment: Same error. Which version of openpyxl are you using

Comment: I am on the latest one. Try updating openpyxl.